# Unchecked cast problem

Tags: java, casting

Hey, I'm trying to implement the ShellSort algorithm and now I got a problem:

`warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast`
`found   : java.util.Vector`
`required: java.util.Vector<java.lang.Object>`
`Vector<Object> vcur = (Vector<Object>)currentCols[tcur];`
Same with `vtmp`.

I don't know where the problem is. It would be really great if you could help me. :)
This is my code:

```
public static Vector<Object> shellSort(Vector<Object> ul) {
    int lcount = ul.size();
    int colcount = 4; // 2^x
    Vector[] currentCols = { ul };
    for(; colcount > 0; colcount = (colcount / 2)) {
        Vector[] tmpCols = new Vector[colcount];
        for(int t1 = 0; t1 < colcount; t1++) {
            tmpCols[t1] = new Vector<Object>();
        }
        int tcur = 0;
        int tcurlvl = 0;
        int ttmp = 0;
        for(int t2 = 0; t2 < lcount; t2++) {
            Vector<Object> vcur = (Vector<Object>)currentCols[tcur];
            Vector<Object> vtmp = (Vector<Object>)tmpCols[ttmp];
            vtmp.addElement((Object)vcur.elementAt(tcurlvl));

            // step to next place
            tcur++;
            ttmp++;
            if(tcur == currentCols.length) { tcur = 0; tcurlvl++; }
            if(ttmp == tmpCols.length) { ttmp = 0; }
        }
    }
    return ul;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This still won't fix the issue (you code doesn't work... never sorts) but it is updated to use List instead of Vector (Vector is obsolete, cannot be deprecated since official APIs depend on it).  Unless you need the synchronization built into Vector use List/ArrayList instead.

I also changed the array creation to be closer to generic (cannot truly do generic array creation).

Finally I made the whole method generic so that it can work typesafely with things other than Object (so a List or List, etc...).

It still gives warnings though.  Perhaps you should work on getting the code to work properly before you worry about this particular warning (normally I would not suggest that, but with generics that can sometimes be a better way to do it).

```
public static <T> List<T> shellSort(List<T> ul) 
{
    int lcount = ul.size();
    int colcount = 4; // 2^x

    List<T>[] currentCols = (List<T>[])Array.newInstance(List.class, 1);
    currentCols[0] = ul;

    for(; colcount > 0; colcount = (colcount / 2))
    {
        List<T>[] tmpCols = (List<T>[])Array.newInstance(List.class, colcount);

        for(int t1 = 0; t1 < colcount; t1++)
        {
            tmpCols[t1] = new ArrayList<T>();
        }

        int tcur = 0;
        int tcurlvl = 0;
        int ttmp = 0;

        for(int t2 = 0; t2 < lcount; t2++)
        {
            List<T> vcur = currentCols[tcur];
            List<T> vtmp = tmpCols[ttmp];
            vtmp.add(vcur.get(tcurlvl));

            // step to next place
            tcur++;
            ttmp++;
            if(tcur == currentCols.length) { tcur = 0; tcurlvl++; }
            if(ttmp == tmpCols.length) { ttmp = 0; }
        }
    }

    return ul;
}
```

Comment: After trying your code and fixing it a bit there it is again: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.util.List<T>[]
            List<T>[] tmpCols = (List<T>[])Array.newInstance(List.class, colcount);

Comment: Yup.  There isn't a way to remove the complaint (that I know of) but this code is closer to what you are after (even if you just take the Array.newInstance code).  Generally a compiler warning is a bad thing, in this case, since there isn't a way around it, you just have to accept it.

Comment: Your use of Array.newInstance is incorrect. You are creating an array of 'List's. Even a simple new Object[size]; would have been better

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem here is type erasure.  At run-time, Vector is simply Vector.  For example:

```
Vector<String> stuff = new Vector<String>()
Vector<Object> objects = (Vector<Object>)stuff
```

It will compile, but fail at runtime when you try to put an Int into objects.

Comment: Java doesn't let you cast like that, last i checked -- for exactly the reason you've given.

Comment: Apparently it's letting him cast like that, but giving him an unchecked cast warning?

Comment: More likely the warning is about the `Vector[]` declarations in the code.  `Vector[]` and `Vector<Object>[]` may look alike in bytecode, but they're not exactly the same to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring `currentCols`?

```
Vector[] currentCols = { ul };
```

This array always contains one element - the `ul`. Just replace `currentCols[..]` with `ul` and the error will also go away.