# How to resolve "Unchecked cast" when using a Vector with Object?

Tags: java, android, vector, casting, compiler-warnings

I've been handed some code to check SMS data, and there is a filter function using a vector cast, that is now causing the compile warning:

**`Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.Vector<xxx.Event>'`**

at this location:

```
values = (Vector<Event>) results.values;
                                ^
required: Vector<Event>
found:    Object
```

The code snippet is as follows:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results.count != 0) {
                values = (Vector<Event>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence smsType) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            Vector<Event> eventList = new Vector<>();

            if (smsType.equals("ALL")) {
                results.values = allEvents;
                results.count = allEvents.size();
                return results;
            }
            for (Event event : allEvents) {
                if (event.getType().toString().equals(smsType)) {
                    eventList.add(event);
                }
            }
            results.values = eventList;
            results.count = eventList.size();
            return results;
        }
    };
}
```

I have already looked around at various SO solutions such as: 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176594/when-to-use-generic-methods-and-when-to-use-wild-card),
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201555/unchecked-cast-warning-how-to-avoid-this),
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873190/warning-unchecked-unchecked-cast-when-casting-object-to-arrayliststring),
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114217/unchecked-cast-problem),
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings) and 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274441/java-how-to-handle-unchecked-cast-for-arraymyitem-from-object). 
But I must admit they have only caused more confusion.

In addition there are some suggestions to use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of a [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), but that Vectors have the advantage of being `synchronized` unlike ArrayLists. I have no idea if this is of any importance here.

And **no**, I don't want to `@SuppressWarnings`, but rather try to understand and resolve the problem cleanly using Java 8.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642985/type-safety-unchecked-cast-from-object-to-listmyobject

Comment: @VeneetReddy Thanks for adding to the already long list of confusion! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.util.Vector` shouldn't be used at all, because it's been obsolescent for nineteen years. It carries non-collections cruft we don't need. Use a synchronized or concurrent list if you need concurrency. Banish `Vector` (and `Hashtable`) from your toolbox.

`(Vector<Event>)` and other generic casts will always be unchecked because generic types are not reifiable. You need a runtime type token, an object of type `Class<T>`, and use its `cast` method to do a generic cast, but it's probably easier to get over your "I don't want to `@SuppressWarnings`" bigotry and use that annotation properly, as documented in *Effective Java*, by Joshua Bloch.